# Pass variable to dialog variable in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a button that opens up a dialog containing another html file. What I would like to be able to do is pass a variable to the dialog. This is what I have.

```js
var html = ""; 
var PLAN_ID = '1234';
html += "<div>"
html += '<a href="formFinal.html?Planid=' + PLAN_ID +'" data-rel="dialog" data role="button">Final</a>'
html += "</div>"
```

The PLAN_ID variable is the one that I wish to push to the formFinal.html. I can populate a hidden text input on the dialog with the following code.

```js
$(document).on('pageshow', '#FinalPostPage', function(e) {
  var page = $(this);
  var query = page.data("url").split("?")[1];
  var planid = query.split("=")[1];
  $("input[name=Title]",this).val(planid);    
})
```

I can use this but the variable doesn't populate until after the formFinal.html page loads it seems. I need the variable to be used while the page develops. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `localStorage` to transfer data from this page to the other page.

When you're creating the button, add the `PLAN_ID` variable as a `data-*` attribute to the `a` and also create an id/class for it :

```
var html = ""; 
var PLAN_ID = '1234';
html += "<div>"
html += '<a href="formFinal.html" id="dialog-send" data-planid="' + PLAN_ID + '" data-rel="dialog" data role="button">Final</a>'
html += "</div>"
```

Write a `click` event for the button click :

```
$(document).on("click", '#dialog-send' ,function(e) {
   //prevent default action. we dont want it to redirect. Just yet. 
   e.preventDefault();
   //set item in localStorage.
   localStorage["plan_id"] = $(this).data("planid");
   //then use changePage to redirect 
   $.mobile.changePage(this.href, {transition: 'pop', role: 'dialog'});     
});
```

In your `pageshow` event,

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#FinalPostPage', function(e) {
  var page = $(this);
  //var query = page.data("url").split("?")[1];
  //get plan id from localStorage 
  var planid = localStorage["plan_id"];
  $("input[name=Title]",this).val(planid);    
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay.. I really like the way this is going. Never used local storage before. I am a little new to jQuery Mobile. So... how do I call the localStorage variable? I see that the "title" input is not showing the value on my Ripple Emulator. Something is a miss. I was showing previously.

Comment: You can use local storage just like how I did.that's the way you call it. As for local storage value, you canccheck in it resources tab of chrome wheels. You run the app.if it works on chrome, it'll work on your emulator.